# How to leave a space before the first word in the section

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

[image]I want to leave a small space before the first word in each paragraph
I know how to do that by leaving one empty line between this paragraph and the last one (as the image shows)

but I can't do this for the first paragraph in the section since there is no paragraph above this paragraph

Comment: On order to help us to help you, please never post screen captures nor code snippets, but compilable MWE (ie Minimal (non-)Working Example).

Comment: Maybe the `indentfirst` package is helpful here.